# How to draw Arc know only startpoint and endpoint in 2D?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, arc-length

I have got short question: How to draw Arc in 2 demension know only start and end point in OpenGL?

Actually, something already wrote, however, this algorithm does not accomplish its purpose. Here we go:

```
 1. Get startXY
 2. Get endXY
 3. Const num_segments = numeric below than 0
 4. Calc midPoint.SetXY((start.x + end.x) / 2, (start.y + end.y) / 2)
 5. Calc diameter = sqrt(pow((end.x - start.y), 2) + pow((end.y -
    start.y), 2));
 6. Calc start_angle = atan2(start.y - midPoint.y, start.x -
    midPoint.x);
 7. Calc end_angle = atan2(end.y - midPoint.y, end.y - midPoint.x);
 8. Calc r = sqrt(((midPoint.x - start.x)*(midPoint.x - start.x)) +
    ((midPoint.y - start.y)*(midPoint.y - start.y)));
 9. Calc theta = end_angle / num_segments;
 10. Calc tangetial_factor = tanf(theta);
 11. Calc float radial_factor = cosf(theta);
 12. Calc x = r * cosf(start_angle); //we now start at the start angle
 13. Calc y = r * sinf(start_angle);
 14. for (int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++)
        drawXY(x + midPoint.x, windowHeight - (y + midPoint.y));
        float tx = -y;
        float ty = x;
        x += tx * tangetial_factor;
        y += ty * tangetial_factor;
        x *= radial_factor;
        y *= radial_factor;
 15. endFor
```

Where I made a mistake? Is there a faster way to draw semi-circle?

Comment: This seems to draw only half circles passing from the two endpoints, if you want something different you should also give the radius of the circle or the tangent angle to one point.

Comment: 1) Oddly you compute on line 9 a Theta that you don't use 2) If you only want one of the two half circles having diameter AB where A and B are the start and end points, you can largely shorten this program.

Comment: If the arcs are always half circles, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907641/318422) for my detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for the equation of the circle using $(x_{start}, y_{start})$ and $(x_{end}, y_{end})$ as two endpoints of its diameter is:-

$$(x - x_{start})(x - x_{end}) + (y - y_{start})(y - y_{end}) = 0$$

It saves some time than going through the process of finding the midpoint.

Comment: Your equation is exact (for a complete circle with this diameter), but 1) finding the midpoint is not that time-consuming... 2) More important, how do you use this equation for building an algorithm to draw in an effective way one of the half circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_s,y_s)$ and $(x_e,y_e)$ denote the coord. of start and end points. Let $(x_m,y_m)$ be those of their midpoint.

Choose $\varepsilon=+1$ (resp. $\varepsilon=-1$) if you want a direct (resp. inverse) half circle.

This half-circle can be plotted with the simple formulas:

> $$\cases{x=x_m+(x_s-x_m) \cos(t)+\varepsilon(y_s-y_m)\sin(t)\\y=y_m+(y_s-y_m) \cos(t)-\varepsilon(x_s-x_m)\sin(t)} \ \ \text{for} \ \ t=0...\pi \ \ \text{with a certain time step.}$$

Simple explanation : formulas above come from the following description

$$\tag{1}\pmatrix{x(t)-x_m\\y(t)-y_m}=\cos(t)\pmatrix{(x_s-x_m)\\(y_s-y_m)}+\sin(t)\pmatrix{\varepsilon(y_s-y_m)\\-\varepsilon(x_s-x_m)}$$

by complete "analogy" with the description of (half) unit circle as being the set:

$$\pmatrix{x\\y}=\cos(t)\vec{i}+\sin(t)\vec{j},$$

with the replacement of $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ by vectors $\vec{I}$ and $\vec{J}$, adapted to the half circle to be drawn. Vector $\vec{I}$ is quite natural ; $\vec{J}$ is chosen such as being orthogonal to $\vec{I}$ (dot product = 0) with the same norm, but orientation depending on $\varepsilon$).

Remark: To underline the "transformational aspect", formula (1) could have been written in the equivalent matrix form:

$$\pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)}=\pmatrix{x_m\\y_m}+\pmatrix{(x_s-x_m)&\varepsilon(y_s-y_m)\\(y_s-y_m)&-\varepsilon(x_s-x_m)}\pmatrix{\cos(t)\\ \sin(t)}$$

Comment: I did a little mistake that I just corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

By arc do you mean a semi-circle?

If so,the given points are at either end of the diameter of a circle.

$$ (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = R^2 $$

where for full circle we have:

$$ h = ( x_{start} + x_{end})/2,\,k = (y_{start} + y_{end})/2 ,\, 4 R^2 = ( x_{start} - x_{end}) ^2 + ( y_{start} - y_{end}) ^2 $$

Parametric form

$$ x= h + R \cos (t- \beta),\,y= k + R \sin (t- \beta),\, \tan \beta = \frac{y_{start} -k}{x_{start} -h} ;  ( 0<t< \pi);$$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by arc any part of a circle there are an infinite number of circles going through two points.
If you mean half of a circle there are TWO (for example upper half and lower half or left half and right half of a circle). So two points are still ambiguous (unless any of the two satisfies) defining a half circle.

I don't know OpenGL but in Java there is a drawArc function with input x, y defining the left uppercorner of the boundingbox and h , w defining the size of the box for the arc. For circles h = w. Then it needs the start angle (defined by a line through your points) and an extend in degrees which for half circles will be 180 or - 180 depending which half circle you want.